# Trying to give role to member on his/her birthday then removing it after 24 hours (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So, I've been trying to make my bot send embed message on member's birthday, I did it. Now I want to make my bot auto-assign birthday role to the member of guild, then auto-removing it after member's birthday has passed.

My logic is simple, if the day on the database equals to time zone date, bot will send message to specific channel mentioning user, then celebrate his/her birthday on embed message. Then, bot will give birthday role to member which appears on top of the discord server roles list.

I've tried to make this logic work, however, there is a problem that I cannot quite understand. It must be rather simple thing to solve, but I do not know how to solve it.

Bot sends the embed message on the channel but does not give the role.
On console, it shows these errors:

```
6|dogumgunu  | TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'remove')
6|dogumgunu  |     at C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Archive\DC-Bots\dogumgunu\src\events\schedule.js:52:34
6|dogumgunu  |     at CoreMongooseArray.forEach (<anonymous>)
6|dogumgunu  |     at C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Archive\DC-Bots\dogumgunu\src\events\schedule.js:31:30
6|dogumgunu  |     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
6|dogumgunu  |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
6|dogumgunu  | TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')
6|dogumgunu  |     at C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Archive\DC-Bots\dogumgunu\src\events\schedule.js:50:34
6|dogumgunu  |     at CoreMongooseArray.forEach (<anonymous>)
6|dogumgunu  |     at C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Archive\DC-Bots\dogumgunu\src\events\schedule.js:31:30
6|dogumgunu  |     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
6|dogumgunu  |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

I cannot understand these errors because everything seems to be in order.

My code (schedule.js):

```
const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
var cron = require('node-cron');
const { collection } = require('../models/Server.js');
const ServerRepository = require("../repositories/server-repository.js");

module.exports = async(client) => {
    await client.mongoose.init()
    cron.schedule('* * * * * *', () => {
        // get the current date so we can compare dates later when verifying birthdays
        const date = new Date();
        const currentMonth = date.getMonth() + 1;
        const currentDay = date.getDate();

        // get the servers
        client.guilds.cache.forEach(async(guild, message) => {
            const dbServer = await ServerRepository.findOrCreate(guild);
            let flag = false;
            let birthdayChannel = null;
            guild.channels.cache.forEach(channel => {
                if (channel.name == '・doğum-günleri') {
                    flag = true;
                    birthdayChannel = channel
                }
            })
            if (!flag) {
                birthdayChannel = await guild.channels.create("・doğum-günleri", "text/voice");
            }

            dbServer.members.forEach(member => {
                const month = member.birthday.getMonth() + 1;
                const day = member.birthday.getDate();
                const role = guild.roles.cache.get("881403012784992266");
                if (month === currentMonth && day === currentDay) {
                    const dogumgunumesaji = new MessageEmbed()
                        .setColor('#e91e63')
                        .setTitle(` Doğum Gününüz Kutlu Olsun!`)
                        .setURL('https://www.duslergezegeni.com/')
                        .setAuthor('Düşler Gezegeni', 'https://i.imgur.com/xvwKU93.png', 'https://www.duslergezegeni.com')
                        .setDescription(`Merhaba Sn. <@${member.discord_id}>,\n **Düşler Gezegeni** yönetim kadrosu olarak doğum gününüzü en içten dileklerimizle kutluyoruz. Nice geçecek mutlu seneleriniz, nice huzur dolu hatıralarınız olsun. Hep beraber hayallerle dolu geleceğe.\n*Saygılarımızla,*\n***Düşler Gezegeni***\n`)
                        .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/Cs2guE7.jpg')
                        .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/xvwKU93.png')
                        .setTimestamp()
                        .setFooter('Düşler Gezegeni | www.duslergezegeni.com', 'https://i.imgur.com/xvwKU93.png');
                    birthdayChannel.send(embed = dogumgunumesaji);
                    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("GuildID");
                    const BirthdayRole = guild.roles.cache.get('RoleID');
                    member.roles.add(BirthdayRole).catch(console.error); //problem is here
                } else if (month !== currentMonth && day !== currentDay) {
                    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("GuildID");
                    const BirthdayRole = guild.roles.cache.get('RoleID');
                    member.roles.remove(BirthdayRole).catch(console.error); //problem is here
                }
            });


        });
    }, {
        scheduled: true,
        timezone: "Europe/Istanbul"
    });
}
```

I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: `member.roles` is undefined.

Comment: How do you execute this?

Comment: It executes itself automatically by node cron on time. Bot gets user id from mongo database and if the day and month on database equals to server date, it posts the actions on server such as giving roles or posting messages on specific channel and if date on database is not equal to server date, it removes the role.

Comment: Member and role is actually seems to be defined, it should receive member property from dbServer.members.forEach(member part and roles property is from Discord.js library, also about the role it will give and guild is also defined. It will really be beneficial if I use some help there... I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Is bot not get the member property, or member property does not fit the right caller?